# Use nginx as proxy to get around CORS

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am trying to use nginx as a proxy so that i can hit an API directly from a browser.

Currently. I wrote the nginx line below,

```
location /binance-api {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    rewrite ^/binance-api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api.binance.com;
}
```

Basically whenever i try to hit the server containing nginx

```
http://nginx-server/binance-api/
```

I want nginx to hit `http://api.binance.com` instead.

But for some reason, judging by inspecting XHR responses, my request URL  itself keeps getting redirected to `https://api.binance.com` and CORS would trigger and my request will fail.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Might there be a redirect to HTTPs on the api side?

Edit: Yep there is a HTTPs redirect so use proxy_pass https://...

Comment: @Ibueker You are correct!